# Access and Office add-in checkbox checked status

Tags: javascript, checkbox, outlook-addin, office-ui-fabric

In my Office add-in I have a checkbox like the following:

```
<div class="ms-CheckBox">
    <input id="inputId" type="checkbox" class="ms-CheckBox-input" />
    <label id="labelId" role="checkbox" class="ms-CheckBox-field" aria-checked="false" name="checkboxA" for="inputId>
        <span class="ms-Label">Text</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve through JavaScript its checked status (or its aria-ckecked status, I'm still not getting the differences between them), which I thought was through `document.getElementById( 'labelId' ).checked`, since it's specified in [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/checkbox) that they have an optional `checked` member, but I only get an `undefined` with it.

I'm very new to these technologies and have a couple concerns:

Does "optional member" mean that I have to explicitly create it so that it exists? If so, how can I do that?

However the `checked` member may come to existance, do I have to manually handle its value every time it's clicked on by the user or is it already internally managed and I simply haven't found the way to access it yet?

Maybe I just can't see a mistake I've made on the html code for the checkbox?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you use any framework: React, Angular or JS only? The HTML you have provided has issue. You mistype the `label` closing tag; Needs to be `</label>` instead of `</label`; missing closing bracket.

Comment: =0 it's true, thank you! It was a copying mistake though, I've checked it and it was well typed on my source. I've edited the post to correct it.

No, I'm not using any framework, just plain JavaScript. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several [sources of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/office-ui-fabric#use-fabric-components) on Office UI Fabric depend on framework you are using or about to use. Your choices are:

- [JavaScript only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-js) (no framework)
- [React](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-react)
- [Angular](http://ngofficeuifabric.com/)

Form the look up table you would choose [JavaScript only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-js) link and follow it to find the component you are interested in. Before that I would suggest to read "[Get Started using Fabric JS](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/GetStarted/GetStarted.html)".

Now when you have documentation on [checkbox component](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/CheckBox/CheckBox.html) of vanilla JS implementation, follow the steps to set up your checkbox. This would include:

- Confirm that you have references to Fabric's CSS and JavaScript on your page
- Copy the HTML from one of the samples below into your page.

  ```
  <div class="ms-CheckBox">
    <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" class="ms-CheckBox-input">
    <label role="checkbox" class="ms-CheckBox-field" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" name="checkboxa">
        <span class="ms-Label">Checkbox</span> 
    </label>
  </div>
  ```
- Add the following  tag to your page, below the references to Fabric's JS, to instantiate all CheckBox components on the page.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var CheckBoxElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-CheckBox");
      for (var i = 0; i < CheckBoxElements.length; i++) {
          new fabric['CheckBox'](CheckBoxElements[i]);
      }
  </script>
  ```
- To get the status of your checkbox use method `getValue()` which returns `true` or `false` whether the component is checked or not.

Comment: It worked! I had seen the `getValue()` before but didn't even know where I had to use it and the objects I had used it on didn't give a very promising result. Much clearer now. Thank you again, Slava!